# Reverse of the statement of uniform continuity on a compact

Tags: functions, compactness, uniform-continuity

If a set $C$ is compact, then all continuous functions on a set $C$ are uniformly continuous.

Does the reverse hold?

**Question** If all continuous functions on a set $C$ are uniformly continuous, then $C$ is compact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider the metric space $(\mathbb{N}, d)$, where $d$ is the Euclidean metric. Then every function is uniformly continuous, but the space is not compact.